# JsonFeature for Ktor Client is unresolved

Tags: android, json, kotlin, ktor

I am starting Ktor based client in android and I want to use any of serializers, currently, the one from kotlinx but the result is the same for others - JsonFeature is not found (highlighted read in the snippet below). What am I missing?

```
class StreamClient {
    val client: HttpClient
    init {
        client = HttpClient(Android) {
            install(JsonFeature) {
                serializer = KotlinxSerializer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle:

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.0.0")
```

Comment: Looks like I was wrong in statement - if I use GSON serializer, JsonFeature is found. I guess I need a full multiplatform setup to use kotlin x serializer.

Comment: Same here but why? It seems that kotlinx has a [JVM branch](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.ktor/ktor-client-serialization-jvm), but ```JsonFeature``` still not available... Frustrating.

Answer (score 13):

This is completely irrelevant to your question but since Ktor 2.0 `JsonFeature` was deprecated in favor of `ContentNegotation`

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    json()
}
```

https://ktor.io/docs/eap/serialization-client.html#install_plugin

Comment: Unresolved reference.  How to import this??

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky `io.ktor.serialization.Configuration.json`; server: `"io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation"`, client: `"io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation"`

Answer (score 7):

As it was said it has been renamed in favor of `ContentNegotiation`

You have to add negotiation dependency:

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation:$ktor_version")
```

Also, JSON

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version")
```

And install it under `httpClient` setup

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    json()
}
```

Details are available here: https://ktor.io/docs/serialization.html#register_json

Comment: Should be `ktor-client-content-negotiation` not `ktor-server-content-negotiation`

Comment: Actually `ktor-server-content-negotiation` worked for me

Comment: It definitely should be ktor-client-content-negotiation

Checkout the docs https://ktor.io/docs/eap/serialization-client.html#register_json

Answer (score 3):

The client documentation for ktor 1.6.8 states that GSON or Jackson can be used in JVM and `kotlinx.serialization` can also be used for Multiplatform setups.

> JsonFeature can be used to serialize/deserialize JSON data when sending requests and receiving responses. This functionality is provided for JVM by using the Gson/Jackson libraries and for Kotlin Multiplatform by using kotlinx.serialization.

https://ktor.io/docs/json.html

I was able to setup the serializer as follows:

```kotlin
val client = HttpClient() {
    install(JsonFeature) {
        serializer = KotlinxSerializer(kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
            prettyPrint = true
            isLenient = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        })
    }
}
```

with these dependencies

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-apache:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version")
```

Answer (score -1):

All dependencies described in the [Json documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/json-feature.html) expose API of the `ktor-client-json` module that contains `JsonFeature`.